# Font-Awesome icon not showing up on Pdf viewer

Tags: pdftex, viewers, fontawesome

I'm using fontawesome package in latex to create a document. The code snippet I'm using is as follows:-

```
 \faGlobe\enspace \href{https://www.some-url.com}{some-url.com}
```

It shows differently when opened on drive pdf viewer(by Google) on Android phones:[image: Incorrect image]

Instead of: [image: Intended image] (It works perfectly on desktop)

Can I add alternative text to this font-awesome icons, So it will render properly?
Packages used:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

Link to doc: https://www.overleaf.com/read/kdrhzrnyjygq

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange. Sadly I can not reproduce the problem on my phone with the PDF from the linked overleaf document. (Neither with the Drive PDF viewer nor with Google PDF viewer.

Comment: I updated the link. Could you check now? It happens if there is Header below or else it displays correctly